# an access violation (segmentation fault) raised in your program

Tags: c++, exception, segmentation-fault

I was working on the first problem on the USACO page, and i got an error that said:

```
Execution error: Your program had this runtime error:
        Exceeded memory or invalid memory reference. The program ran for
        0.000 CPU seconds before the error. It used 3372 KB of memory.
```

I'm pretty sure I know why this is happening: When i run my program, it compiles and executes fine, but as soon as the program is finished, a box pops up saying "main.exe has stopped working...", and then it freezes. When I run the debugger, I get this error: 
`an access violation (segmentation fault) raised in your program`. What does this mean and how do I fix it?
I saw a couple of other threads like this but I wasn't able to fix my program using the other threads' feedback. Here is my code:

```
/*
ID: krishna24
LANG: C++
PROG: ride
*/
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string ride(string comet, string group) {
   int cometsum = 1;
   int groupsum = 1;
   for(int i = 0; i < comet.size(); i++) {
       char ascival = comet[i];
       cometsum = cometsum*((int)ascival-64);
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < group.size(); i++) {
       char ascival = group[i];
       groupsum = groupsum*((int)ascival-64);
   }
   if (groupsum%47 == cometsum%47) cout << "GO";
   else cout << "STAY";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string comet;
    getline(cin, comet);
    string group;
    getline(cin, group);
    ride(comet, group);
}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

PS: Any suggestions on how to make my code more streamlined and efficient would be useful too. :)

EDIT: This didn't work because my `ride()` function didn't return a string. Changing it to `void` solved the problem. Thanks everyone!

Comment: return 1 i guess at the end of main.

Comment: It's likely due to the fact that you don't actually return anything from `string ride()`, as not returning from a function that declares it wants to return something leads to undefined behavior. However, take this as an opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. :) Sidenote @AdnanAkbar: why would you `return 1` instead of `return 0` if nothing happened and the program exited normally? `return 1` is typically understood as "something happened and the program didn't exit nicely." Not that that is the solution to this problem.

Comment: can you provide sample input that causes the problem?

Answer (score 6):

`ride` claims to return a `string`, but you don't actually return anything. I'm very surprised the compiler lets you get away with that; you should enable warnings (`-Wall` for GCC) and maybe even make warnings be errors (`-Werror` for GCC).

Comment: Well, that was easy! I originally had ride() return "GO" or "STAY", but then I changed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ride()` is supposed to return a string, but instead you output to the console. Perhaps at the end of `ride()`, change the code to return the strings:

```
if (groupsum%47 == cometsum%47) return << "GO";
    else return << "STAY";
```

and in `main()` output the results to the console:

```
cout << ride(comet, group);
```

Comment: Get rid of the `<<` - you'd just do `return "GO";` or `return "STAY";`.